# Any evidence it won't be exponentially harder to add more qubits?

Tags: entanglement

I appreciate quantum circuits can solve certain problems exponentially faster than classical circuits.

Q. Are there reasons to believe it won't be double as hard to build a quantum computer with i+1 qubits than one with i qubits?

The state vector doubles in size, so I always imagined it's volatility would double.

Answer (score 1):

See the wikipedia article on the [threshold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_theorem), which proves quantum computation can be done fault tolerantly with polynomial overhead instead of exponential overhead.

Comment: This is correct but it is also important to remind for @Alexander that it assumes the physical error rates to be independent on the number of qubits. Because of crosstalk (among other things) it could be much harder to scale up than predicted.

Comment: But since any physical process is local, it is believed that crosstalk will not prevent the existence of a threshold.

Comment: Interesting. So the theorem assumes a constant error rate p independent of the number of quibits and gates. I'd be happy to accept an answer that provides evidence that the assumption is reasonable for however big circuits the error correction codes output. E.g., for error corrected prime factorization we'd need X quibits, and empirically the empirical failure rate of quibits from 1 to X increases polynomially.

Comment: @AlexanderMathiasen Go look at psiquantum's proposed architecture. The pieces of their system are separated by kilometers of optical fiber. How would the error-per-operation scale polynomially in that kind of setup? All the operations are pretty widely separated in space or time. As soon as you have any sufficiently-good piece of hardware, that you can isolate from the other parts using a network boundary, you are done. There's no longer physical error mechanism that correlate their failures, meteor strikes and nuclear war notwithstanding. And the network boundary is probably massive overkill.